# Beta binomial mean different from actual mean

Tags: r, mean, parameterization, beta-binomial-distribution

I have data that I am fitting a beta binomial distribution to. The VGAM package for R is being used to do this. However, the the mean of the fitting beta binomial distribution is vastly different from that of the actual data. The beta binomial mean appears to be always lower, for example:

```
library("VGAM")
x = c(50,31,94,80,40,71,49,72,79,47,35,95,88,97,43)
y = c(237,297,257,271,143,169,247,150,167,228,124,186,131,276,287)
fit <- vglm(cbind(x,y)~1, betabinomialff)
Coef(fit)
   shape1    shape2 
  6.585537 20.862674
3.05486/(3.05486+21.22942)
  0.1257958
mean(x/y)
  0.3333176
```

I'm not sure how to correct for this or why it is always so different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The beta distribution has two shape parameters, $\alpha$ and $\beta$. The parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be interpreted as the numbers of negative and positive outcomes, respectively.

To fit a model with a beta-binomial distribution using `vglm`, you have to use the numbers of negative and positive outcomes as the dependent variable, i.e., `cbind(x, y - x)` (assuming `y` represents the total number of outcomes):

```
fit <- vglm(cbind(x, y - x) ~ 1, betabinomialff)
```

For your example, you obtain the following parameters:

```
Coef(fit)
#   shape1   shape2 
# 3.284645 6.582308
```

The mean of the beta distribution is defined as

$$\frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta}.$$

You will see that the result matches the observed mean:

```
Coef(fit)[1] / sum(Coef(fit))
#    shape1 
# 0.3328935 

mean(x / y)
# [1] 0.3333176
```